# How to understand the use of 'on' in "three lessons on"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

> **Three lessons on**, Apparition was proving as difficult as ever, though a few more people had managed to Splinch themselves.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I figure "three lessons on" means *after three lessons*, but I'm not quite sure. What's the correct way to understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it means "after three lessons." Good dictionaries should have this meaning, but since "on" is one of those words that are used for a million different things in English, you may have to scroll down a bit to find it.

[Cambridge Dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on):

> **on** *adverb* **(MOVING FORWARD)**
>
> <sup>B2</sup> **continuing forward in time or space:**
>
> *They never spoke to each other **from that day** on (= after that day).*
>
> *What are you doing **later** on?*
>
> *When you're done with it, would you pass it on to Paul?*
>
> <sup>UK</sup> *Move on, please, and let the ambulance through.*
>
> <sup>UK</sup> *You cycle on and I'll meet you there.*

For what it's worth, as an American I don't agree that the last two examples are UK-specific. These usages are found in Am.E too.